# Migration with ID already exists

Tags: migrations

My migration is not showing up in `drush migrate-status`. When I try to reimport them with `drush config-import --partial --source="modules/custom/complinetmigration/config/install"` I get the following error message.

> The import failed due for the following reasons:
>   Unexpected error during import with operation create for
>   migrate_plus.migration.complinet_xml_to_node2: *migration* entity with ID *market_center_to_D8* already exists.

Comment: This could be because the `migrate_plus.migration.complinet_xml_to_node2` was renamed, or there is already another migrate config with the id `market_center_to_D8`.

You can find the config id in the data column of the config table in the database.

Answer (score 2):

- Try deleting the existing migration by doing `drush cdel migrate_plus.migration.MIGRATION_ID`
- I think the `id` in your YML file is not the same as the `MIGRATION_ID` part of your YML file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some way below:

1. Try import single with drupal cis (this option will override if config exited)
2. Delete config with command:

   drush config-delete migrate_plus.migration.complinet_xml_to_node2

and import again.